# Including PowerShell command in Windows Bash

Tags: bash, powershell

Using Bash commands, I set up a Bash scrip to do some trivial stuffs, which is easier to done through Bash. Owing to a particular command, here is javac, that have been exclusively integrated in PowerShell, I wonder is there any way to include a PowerShell command inside the Bash script?
Something like this:

```
#bash script    
rsync -r --exclude='*.class' ../../project ./
PowerShell javac ./project/*.java
allDirs=$(ls -d /*)
```

Comment: Does that not work?

Comment: No, it prompted: "PowerShell: command not found"

Comment: What's your OS?

Comment: Windows 10 indeed.

Comment: What hapens when you type `which PowerShell` in your terminal ?

Comment: Nothing, ready to get next command.

Comment: You're doing something wrong. It should display either a path (like `/mnt/c/Windows/PowerShell.exe`) or `PowerShell not found`

Comment: Well, it should return something like `C:/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe`

Comment: It would return it when I type: `which PowerShell.exe`
Also in script it works properly.

Comment: Well try using PowerShell.exe instead of PowerShell then?

Comment: Die you check, whether the command is in your PATH?

Comment: Yes it is within the PATH: `/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/`

Comment: Just run `javac ./project/*.java`.  Specify the full path if it's not in the path.

Comment: Although the java path is added to PATH but when I type javac command it displays:
`Command 'javac' not found`

Comment: It is added like this: ‍`/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_251/bin‍‍‍`

Comment: Funny! javac.exe is executable as well as PowerShell.exe. Seems .exe is essential regarding using packages installed externally.